# fetch data where column not null not working

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

try to fetch data by CodeIgniter active record where field in not empty

```
  $this->db->select('tags');
  $this->db->where('tags IS NOT NULL', null, false);
  $this->db->from('users');
  $query = $this->db->get();  
  return $query->result();
```

not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be this will help you

```
 $this->db->select('tags');
 $this->db->where('tags IS NOT NULL');
 $this->db->from('users');
 $query = $this->db->get();  
 return $query->result();
```

Comment: $this->db->where('tags !=',""); thanks for your time. this works for me